# write a bash script to organize files by their type

Tags: linux, bash, directory

Given a directory with these files for example.

```
bike.png
car.jpg
comedy.mov
error.log
horror.avi
info.txt
interview.mp3
song.flac
tree-small.jpeg
11.10.2017_y
some-directory
nested-file.log
```

I am trying to write a bash script that would create 3 folders "Music, Videos, Images" and organize these files into their type folder and deletes .log files.

Music is all flac/mp3 files, Images are jpeg/png files, and Videos are all avi/mov files.

The final directory structure should look like this.

```
images/
     bike.png
     car.jpg
music/
     interview.mp3
     song.flac
videos/
     comedy.mov
     horror.avi
info.txt
tree-small.jpeg
11.10.2017_y
some-directory/
     nested-file.log
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this do it?

```sh
#!/bin/sh

mkdir music videos images
mv *.flac *.mp3 music/
mv *.jpeg *.png images/
mv *.avi *.mov videos/
rm *.log
```